# I am a graduate student traveling to France for a 5-day summer academic workshop at a university. Proof of accommodation?

Tags: visas, france, schengen-visas, conferences

The university will be providing temporary accommodation. The website of the consulate I am applying at (http://www.consulfrance-losangeles.org/spip.php?article2904) does not provide information on what type of documentation to show for temporary stay at a university.

Answer (score 2):

The premise of your question is incorrect:

> The website of the consulate I am applying at (http://www.consulfrance-losangeles.org/spip.php?article2904) does not provide information on what type of documentation to show for temporary stay at a university.

In fact, item 4 on that page is

> 4- Short stay visa for studies (90 days or under)

That links to http://www.consulfrance-losangeles.org/spip.php?article792, including a section headed "Application Requirements," which has as its item 12 (emphasis added)

> 12 — PROOF OF ACCOMMODATION
>
> - Confirmed hotel reservations for your entire stay in the Schengen states **or a letter from the school listing the full address of accommodation and length of stay.** Your dates of accommodation must match your flight reservations (arrival and departure date in the Schengen area).
> - or, if you are staying with friends or family, original of "Attestation d’Accueil" that your host has to request at the City Hall (Mairie) in France + ONE COPY

Comment: Can I apply for a study visa to attend a 5 day workshop? I thought I had to enroll in a university course.

Comment: @J.Doe there's no other category on the page that you linked to that applies to you, and I don't see anything in this category that excludes short-term educational programs like a workshop.  Have you asked the school about it?

Comment: in france, university course is usually more than 90 days.

Comment: @francois of course. And the visa we're discussing applies only to stays of 90 days or fewer. What conclusion would you draw from these two facts?